# Reset Order Numerb and Invoice 2.4.4

Tags: database, magento2.4

i finish to do a lot of test so now i'd like to reset order progressive number and invoices.. Anyone can help me with mysql code for doing this reset?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to keep the old orders?or it's fine to delete them?

Comment: For deleting all order i have a plugin and is not a problem. I'd like to start from order 0001 and invoice 0001 after deleting all orders. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Truncate the tables instead of deleting all the rows.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_order
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_invoice
```

Truncate all the order & invoice related tables

or you can use the below query to alter the auto_increment value

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset Increment value

Truncate `sequence_order_*` and `sequence_invoice_*` tables

If you want to change logic (like prefix/suffix) you can also review data in `sales_sequence_profile` and `sales_sequence_meta`

Also might be useful table to understand is `eav_entity_type`